# Trying to update a component in patch organization says Managed Package Patch Modification Exception

Tags: visualforce, managed-package

I have a component for which I modified some lines in javascript.

> **Error: Managed Package Patch Modification Exception: A change was made to the patch release that will change the visible behavior of the
>   application: Visualforce Component: xxForm: Cannot change attribute
>   properties in a patch.**

It is throwing the above error. I tried with an empty space it was not updating the component in the patch organization.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this before, it is a bug in the platform. If your sure you have not changed the 'access' attribute on your component or any of its attributes. Recommend you raise a support call, they sorted it for us.